# asp.net page without code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page with a code behind file. The code behind file contains no logic so I can remove it if I want to. Replacing it with a html file is not an option.

Will there be performance difference if I remove the code behind file?

Answer (score 8):

Nothing that you should ever worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The performance benefit would be marginal, if anything.

I don't think that this is something you should be concerning yourself with, if you can remove the CodeBehind file to cleanup your file structure and your actual page, then go for it.

Every little helps when it comes to cleaning up your code and removing unnecessary stuff, you never know how big an application's codebase might grow.